# How to set max and min limit of zoom for an ID of an element with JS or JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my app I've a `DIV` tag with id `mainDiv`

and I've applied zooming, but the problem is its zooming without a limit means no upper limit and lower limit.

I'm tring in google but its showing google map api's but I need `css` properties or js or jquery fixes.

The code is like this: Its SVG ZOOMING

```
if(evt.wheelDelta)
        delta = evt.wheelDelta / 3600; // Chrome/Safari
    else
        delta = evt.detail / -90; // Mozilla

    var z = 1 + delta; // Zoom factor: 0.9/1.1

    var g = getRoot(svgDoc);

    var p = getEventPoint(evt);

    p = p.matrixTransform(g.getCTM().inverse());

    // Compute new scale matrix in current mouse position
    var k = root.createSVGMatrix().translate(p.x, p.y).scale(z).translate(-p.x, -p.y);

        setCTM(g, g.getCTM().multiply(k));

    if(typeof(stateTf) == "undefined")
        stateTf = g.getCTM().inverse();

    stateTf = stateTf.multiply(k.inverse());
```

please help

Comment: which plugin did you used for zooming with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

anything like this?

```
(function ($) {

var $parent = $('#floor_plan');

if($parent.length) {

    // set-up panzoom
    var $panzoom = $parent.find('.panzoom').panzoom({
        increment       : 0.5,
        minScale        : 1,
        maxScale        : 2,
        startTransform  : 'scale(4.0)',
        $zoomIn         : $parent.find('A[href=#zoom_in]'),
        $zoomOut        : $parent.find('A[href=#zoom_out]'),
        contain         : 'invert'
    }).panzoom('zoom', true);

    // handle scrolling in and out
    $panzoom.parent().on('mousewheel.focal', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var delta = e.delta || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
        var zoomOut = delta ? delta < 0 : e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0;

        $panzoom.panzoom('zoom', zoomOut, {
            increment   : 0.1,
            animate     : false,
            focal       : e
        });
    });
}
```

})(jQuery);

http://jsfiddle.net/576a4qeh/1/